# How to change the grouping of items in a list?

Tags: python, list, grouping

So if I have a list like this:

```
x = [0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9]
```

How do I convert this list into something like this:

```
x = [01,23,45,67,89]
```

How can I do that?

I know about the built in `zip` function, 
but I don't want a `tuple` and I want 2 numbers grouped into 1.

Comment: modified `x` list consist of `str` objects or `int`s?

Comment: 01 is not a valid integer representation in Python... do you mean the function that combines integers should return strings? or are your inputs actually strings to begin with?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try this:

```
x = [0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9]

x = map(str, x)

new_list = map(int, [x[i]+x[i+1] for i in range(0, len(x)-1, 2)])
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply! I will try it!

Comment: Note that in python 3 `map` returns a generator object instead of a list, so you'll have to do `x = list(map(str, x))` or `x = [str(i) for i in x]`.

Comment: I'm using python 3 so I'll have to try that. Thanks Rawing

Comment: Instead of converting the two numbers into strings and the result back to an integer, why not use just `x[i]*10 + x[i+1]`? Of course in either case the `01` will be displayed as `1`...

Comment: I typed in your code and when I try to `print()` the value, it returns a hex memory location for some reason: `<map object at 0x05485610>`

Comment: @InfinityLoop you have to call list() before map to return a list

Comment: no need to use map though 'new_list = [int(str(x[i])+str(x[i+1])) for i in range(0, len(x)-1, 2)] '

Comment: Got it! It works! Thanks!
I did: 
`x = list(map(str, x)`

Comment: I did: 

`x = list(map(str, x)`

then

`new_list = map(int, [x[i]+x[i+1] for i in range(0, len(x)-1, 2)])`

and it grouped the numbers the way I was looking for though I'm not sure its the 'best' way, it worked.

Answer (score 2):

Using zip and list comprehensions, assuming data type is going from list of ints to list of strings:

```
In [1]: x = [0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9]

In [2]: pairs = zip(x[::2], x[1::2])

In [3]: pairs
Out[3]: [(0, 1), (2, 3), (4, 5), (6, 7), (8, 9)]

In [4]: [str(fst) + str(snd) for fst, snd in pairs] 
Out[4]: ['01', '23', '45', '67', '89']
```

Answer (score 1):

This is much easier to understand and is a one liner:

```
 # l = list of string of items in list u with index(i) and index(i+1) and i increments by 2
 l = [ str( u[i]) + str( u[i+1]) for i in range( 0, len(u), 2)]
```

Comment: considering guido wanted to get rid of map and the function being mapped to the list is nothing large this is probably the better answer, and likely faster too